# How do I set the position of a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

So as far as I know, the "protocol method":

```
(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Automatically sets the bounds of the cell I created. This is all fine and dandy for my of the `UICollectionViewCells`, but I need one of them to be in a location that I specify. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I assume you are also using an instance of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as your collection view's layout object?

If so, the quick and dirty answer is to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and override the `-layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.item == 2) // or whatever specific item you're trying to override
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        layoutAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100); // or whatever...
        return layoutAttributes;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

You will probably also need to override `-layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *layoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementInRect:rect];
    if (CGRectContainsRect(rect, CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))) // replace this CGRectMake with the custom frame of your cell...
    {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        layoutAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100); // or whatever...
        return [layoutAttributes arrayByAddingObject:layoutAttributes];
    }
    else
    {
        return layoutAttributes;
    }
}
```

Then use your new subclass in place of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` when you create your collection view.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I was already using a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout called [lxreorderablecollectionviewflowlayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout) but I just played around with the existing code in it along with the things you provided and got it working.

Comment: in the layoutAttributesForElementsInRect method NSArray *layoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementInRect:rect]; should be replaced with NSArray *layoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect rect];

Comment: @JoshHinman Can you explain what layoutAttributesForElementsInRect does and why it also has to be overridden

Comment: indexPath doesn't exist in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect